# Jira REST API returns error when creating issue

Tags: c#, api, jira-rest-api

My goal is to use the Jira REST API to create an issue. But as of now I am getting an error **(405) Method Not Allowed.**

I have checked in the Jira Properties if the Jira Remote APIs are switched on.
Under:

*JIRA Configuration > General Configuration > Allow Remote API Calls is ON.*

I have also checked my JSON string submitted which looks fine to me:

```
"{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"CTTS\"},\"summary\":\"Api  Test\",\"description\":\"Test\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Story\"}}}"
```

My current code to call the API is following:

```
public JiraApiResponseObject CreateRequest(JSONstring)
    {
        jiraRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://MyJiraUrl.net/rest/api/2/issue");

        jiraRequest.Method = "POST";
        jiraRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        jiraRequest.Accept = "application/json";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(jiraRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(JSONstring);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)jiraRequest.GetResponse();
        return jiraReturnObject;
    }
```

I currently dont know what is causing the error. I just get the **(405) Method Not Allowed** error from the remote server, when i actually would expect a API response.

Comment: Are you positive that that endpoint supports a PUT request?  It apparently disagrees.

Comment: Sorry for that i was just testing it out actually i used POST, i corrected it in the code.

Comment: Okay, then, my question remains the same.  Are you positive that that endpoint supports POST requests?  Because it apparently still disagrees.  Please share the documentation for the endpoint you're trying to access.

Comment: I am almost certain that it supports POST calls. This is the documentation of the endpoint i am trying to access:
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/

Comment: How do you authenticate in your code? In the documentation they provide '-u charlie:charlie' in the curl example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There Is an Authorization Header Missing in the WebRequest. Jira needs such a header to confirm that only authorized users can access the API's.

This Authorization String is is build as follows:

```
"Basic username:api_token"
```

The api_token can be generated in the Jira Cloud and needs to be base64-encoded.

Here is what I would do:

1. Generate an API token for Jira using your Atlassian Account: https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens.
2. Build a string of the form username:api_token.
3. Base64-encode encode the string.
4. Supply an Authorization header with content Basic followed by the encoded string.

For example, the string fred:fred encodes to ZnJlZDpmcmVk in base64, so you would add the following to your request:

```
jiraRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "UserName" + Base64Encode(apiToken);
```